# Disable PowerApps button on list/document library

Tags: sharepoint

I wish to remove the PowerApps button from the command bar on e.g. document libraries on a site. But it does not seem to work. N.B. Automate/Flow button are removed / disable as expected.
My initial test was with a PnP template where I set the websettings nodes attr, like this:

```
<pnp:WebSettings Title="{parameter:SiteTitle}" DisableFlows="true" DisableAppViews="true"
```

But it did removed the PowerApps button.
Then I tried there PnP PowerShell snippets but without any luck:

```
$web = get-pnpweb
$web.DisableAppViews = $true
$web.DisableFlows = $true
$web.Update()
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

```
$ctx = Get-PnPContext
$ctx.Site.DisableAppViews = $true;
$ctx.Site.DisableFlows = $true;
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

(Snippet pasted from https://www.cloudappie.nl/disabling-flow-powerapps-buttons/)
I’m petty sure this was working like 2 weeks ago. Any ideas why I can disable PowerApps button.

Answer (score 0):

You could use spfx to upload custom css file to sharepoint online to hide special button.

Example on how to upload css file in spfx:

https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss

similar issue:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/280681/how-to-hide-the-button/280683#280683

Comment: Hey @Amos_MSFT. Thank you for your post. But I don't see the first link that as a viable option. The second link is what I've tried :(